# reading makefile variables from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, makefile

I have a `makefile` in which I'm trying to set some variables which already exist in a bash script which I wrote called: `set-vars.sh` (it just contains variable names and values).

I'm using these variables in several other `bash` scripts. I need to also be able to use them in my `makefile`.

After a lot of researching and trying to figure out what is the best way to set variables from a `bash` script in `makefile`, I've found a way which works; which is as follows:

**`set-vars.sh`:**

```
# set vars
foo=FOO1
bar=BAR1
baz=BAZ1

# if a command line arg is given (e.g. foo) 
# echo value command line arg (e.g. echo $foo)

if ! [ -z ${1+x} ]; then echo ${!1}; fi
```

The magic here is the last line which `echo`es the value of a variable the name of which is provided in the command line argument, IF there is a command line argument. I call this script in the `makefile` and provide the variable name and use the `echo`ed value to set the `makefile` variables.

**`Makefile`:**

```
.PHONY:  target1 target2 target3

export foo = $(shell sh set-vars.sh foo)

target1:
    @echo $(foo)

# ... other targets which reference $(foo) ...
```

This works, but it is probably a *hacky* way of doing it. I'm wondering if there is a more simple, elegant way to do what I want to do.

I've come across several similar questions and answers on StackOverflow but didn't find anything that works with my example. If there is an answer already which I missed, please point me to it.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can't set the variables in the shell that calls `make`, or put them on the `make` command line?

Comment: Do other scripts need that `if ! [ -z...` line?

Comment: @Barmar, I can't put them on make command line because this makefile will be used by other people who may or may not be familiar with the inner workings of this makefile. I want to keep the calling of the makefile as simple as possible... but what do you mean by setting the variables in the shell that calls `make`? Sorry I'm not too proficient in shell scripting.

Comment: @Beta, no this line was added specifically for the makefile so I can set the variables in the makefile using the value which was echo'd from the bash script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define your variables in a file that can be sourced from your shell scripts and included from your Makefile:

```
$ cat vardef.txt
foo=FOO1
bar=BAR1
baz=BAZ1
$ cat set-vars.sh
source ./vardef.txt
echo "$foo $bar $baz"
$ sh ./set-vars.sh
FOO1 BAR1 BAZ1
$ cat Makefile
include vardef.txt
all:
    @echo "$(foo) $(bar) $(baz)"
$ make
FOO1 BAR1 BAZ1
```

Isn't it just wonderful when two languages partly use the same syntax?

Comment: This looks promising... I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Gave it a try. Works well with the `Makefile`, not so well with the shell scripts. Getting this: `subtest.sh: line 3: source: vars.txt: file not found`.

Comment: Did you try `source ./vars.txt` or `source vars.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's less hacky, but you can "create" a file that can be included into Makefile. In runtime. Like this:

```
$(shell grep '=' vars.sh > /tmp/vars.tmp)
include /tmp/vars.tmp
$(shell rm /tmp/vars.tmp)
```

Replace the first line with something more sane.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally considered poor practice for build systems to depend on environment variables because if they do you suddenly have a reproducibility problem when the output depends not only on the command line but also on the state of environment variables.

Having warned you, all environment variables are accessible in `make`, e.g.:

```
user := ${USER} # ${USER} comes from the environment.
all :
    @echo ${user}
```

In other words, have a script that sets the environment variables and invokes `make`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export foo=FOO1
export bar=BAR1
export baz=BAZ1
exec make "$@"
```

---

Alternatively, you can have a shell script with `export foo=FOO1` statements only. This turns out to be valid makefile syntax, so that you can do `include set-vars.sh` in your `Makefile`.

Comment: This would work, but I need to be able to run `make` from the command line, not from a script. I need `make` to be able to get all the correct variables and values under the hood. Thereby creating a level of abstraction where the users don't have to do anything except run `make install` or whatever target they want to run without knowing what's inside the `Makefile`.

Comment: @tamjd1 Added an alternative solution for you.

Comment: Just noticed that @RenaudPacalet originally gave this advice.